# getting the "adal.access.token.key|https://graph.microsoft.com"" from the session (sessionStorage)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, adal

Trying to figure out the access-token for graph call I found this article:
https://piasys.com/blog/getting-an-access-token-for-a-service-in-spfx/
That Shows how to get it with:

`this.aadTokenProvider = await this.context.aadTokenProviderFactory.getTokenProvider(); this.aadTokenProvider.getToken(“https://graph.microsoft.com”);`
But when I do `JSON.stringify(sessionStorage)` at the console, I see it at the end of the JSON
Is there a way to parse the `sessionStorage` to get the token without all the async /await hoops?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that get access token with adal, then call the graph api?

Comment: I meant a way to get the token from the sessionStorage  JSON. one way will be with substring but I was hopping for something like sessionStorage.{???}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token is put into sessionStorage by the auth libraries as a result of those async/await calls.
Could you read the item out of storage and use it, you could, for a while, but those calls ensure you will always get a fresh unexpired token.

Paolo's point with the blog post is not to encourage you to go read from session storage but to use the async/await calls because you will always get a current token

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense now.